# Two phase method in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

Suppose following tableau came after one iteration in first phase of a two phase method problem, here $s_1$ is a surplus variable and $s_2$ is a slack variable $w$ is a artificial variable.

I tried to minimize $W=w$ $\implies$ maximize $-W=-w$

> $$
> \begin{array}{c|c}
>  & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & s_1 & s_2 & w & \text{solution} \\
> \hline
> x_2 & 1/2 & 1 & -1/2 & -1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 5/2 \\
> s_2 & -5/2 & 0 & 1/2 & -1/2 & 1 & 1/2 & 13/2 \\
> \hline
>  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Now we can clearly see that artificial variable is not in basic variable set.but the solution is not optimal. in fact solution is unbounded.

> My problem is can we proceed to second phase after this step?
>
> Even though the $w$ is not in basic solution set $(w=0)$ since the solution is not optimal and unbounded should we stop here?

Comment: Who is $W$? Presumably $W=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$ for some $c_1,c_2,c_2\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: In phase one,we have to minimize the sum of artificial variables.it is $W$

Comment: What is the initial tableau ?

Comment: @Gune what's the initial problem here?